# How to pass data from firebase service worker using postMessage to Angular 4 component

Tags: angular, service-worker, postmessage

How can I pass data from service worker to Angular 4 component? is it possible to use angular service to fix it? 
How to use navigator and PostMessage with angular 4?
Please help me step by step:)

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
  messagingSenderId: ""
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

postMessage({
      msg: "Hey I just got a fetch from you!",
      url: event.request.url
     });
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you're trying to do too much before learning the basics :-)

I urge you to read [Google's intro](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/) to SW and [these guides](https://serviceworke.rs/).