# How to pass data from Service Worker to Component

Tags: angular, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've managed to follow all of the instructions and tutorials to get notifications working in my Angular 9 app when the app is both in the background and the foreground, however I'm using FCM to pass data messages to my application in order to update a realtime dashboard.

In my app.component I have the below:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.messagingService.requestPermission();
this.message = this.messagingService.currentMessage;

navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    console.log('Received a message from service worker: ', event);

    //The below service doesnt exist in this context
    this.messagingService.processMessage(event)

    });
  }
```

I'm able to process messages in my service when the app is in the foreground, but I can't get data into my service when the app is in the background. Can anyone assist?

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201165/how-to-pass-data-from-firebase-service-worker-using-postmessage-to-angular-4-com) question, but obviously there was a couple of issues with that question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41444343/angular-2-window-postmessage) answer that helped me to solve this problem. All that was required was to make the addEventListener an arrow function in order to bind to the this of the component:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.messagingService.requestPermission();
this.message = this.messagingService.currentMessage;

navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', (event) => {

    this.messagingService.processMessage(event)

    });
  }
```

My understanding of 'this' binding is rudamentary at best, so I'd encourage you to do your own reading..